# How to remove the Title Bar of Gnome applications

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, openbox, titlebar, window-decoration

## Problem

##### I have one Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop(`Gnome`) and I want it to be fully black and ideal. As reference, I have taken one Ubuntu20 Server and Installed `openbox` on it.

I hided the title bar of all the applications in `OpenBox` by editing the configurations in `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` and added

```
<application class="*">
      <decor>no</decor>
      <maximized>false</maximized>
    </application>

</applications>
```

So that it will hide the title-bar of all the applications. Also, I am able to achieve my demand. Image shown below as example.
[image: openbox]

I want to perform the same on Gnome Desktop as well, but I don't know which config file to be edited for the same.
Currently, my `Gnome` Looks like this
[image: gnome]

Any help for the following is appreciated
Thank you.

#### NOTE: I don't want to use only terminal, but will be using other applications like Firefox, chrome, VLC, etc. without title-bar

Comment: I am surprised you could hide the client side decorations of Gnome Terminal in Openbox.

Comment: @vanadium Hi, No in ```openbox``` I have used ```xterm``` as I was not having gnome terminal in that. But the point is, not only terminal, I have to hide the title bar from all the applications like terminal, chrome, vlc etc tec.

Comment: A bit confusing - add this information to your answer so the reader is not misled by the two images. Anyway, I answered: the unite extension (and perhaps also pixel saver) can do that. For Gnome Terminal, it will not work directly because it uses CSDecoration. However, Gnome Terminal can be configured to use legacy title bars.

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) are *snap* only systems intended for server use only (not desktop use), being different products to the *year.month* products that can use *snap* packages too, but also *deb* packages - thus allowing desktops.  You mention 20 which implies a product like Ubuntu Core 20.  20 != 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gnome Shell extension [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) by default will hide a legacy title bar for maximized applications. However, it can be configured to hide the title bar for all windows.

Note that this will not remove title header bars of GTK3/GTK4 applications that use Client Side decorations instead of legacy title bars, because the latter are drawn by the application rather than by the window manager.

Comment: Can we use the same for  the applications if not maximized ? Will it hide the  title bar  still?

Comment: This reveals to me that you did not yet test this answer.

Comment: I used this extension and also pixel saver. ```Unite```  was able to hide my title bar when maximized and also tried ```pixelsaver``` but that project is not having regular updates.

Comment: Unite can always hide title bar, also for not maximized windows.

Comment: I tried Unite as well. It is not doing the work I need, I am still seeing those close minimize maximize buttons and name of application. I want to hide all of them

Comment: In my answer, I indicated that it works with legacy title bars, but ot with CSD. It will never work with CSD: you would need to edit the code of the application. Solution: install the forks from Mate or Mint (the x-apps)

Comment: Thanks It worked!

Answer (score 3):

For most applications [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) will be enough, but for certain apps [Rounded Window Corners](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5237/rounded-window-corners/) helps a lot, in addition to Unite.

Besides the rounded corners, there's a **Padding Clipping** option in that extension which can clip/hide title bars, regardless if client side decorations or legacy.

[image]

**This will work on Gnome 44.0 too!**

You can hide specifically the Gnome Terminal title bar like so:

- In dconf-editor change `org.gnome.terminal.legacy.headerbar` from `Default` to `Custom value` - `false`
- In terminal, right click anywhere and go to `Preferences`, `General` and uncheck `Show menubar by default`
- Use `Unite` for hiding the titlebar

*At this point the titlebars should be entirely hidden, but if they are not for whatever reason, use Rounded Window Corners clipping:*

- `Extensions`, `Rounded Window Corners`, `Padding` to clip/hide the titlebar when minimized

You can use the clipping option per application, under the `Custom` tab.

---

The above two extensions will basically make it possible to hide the titlebar wherever you want.

Depending on the app though, in some cases you have to enable the legacy system title bars. One example is Google Chrome too. Note that the legacy title bar option is in Chrome settings:

[image]

Regarding `Pixel Saver` though, note that many report quite some performance issues or even "screen freezing".