# GNOME/OtherDE's Remove all screen top elements (menu/title bars, etc) above application window

Tags: gnome, kde, xfce, mac

I've been using Linux for 10+ years on servers, but only today started trying out the desktop environment on an old MacBook.

On small screens of notebook pcs, I feel the "Top Bar / Title Bar / Menu Bar" combo are not ideal to make best use of the small screen.

I made a little comparison to demonstrate my intent:

[image]

On the left is Mac desktop. Top menu bar can be hidden in recent versions of MacOS.
I like this display mode as I can use 100% of the screen to focus on my coding joys.

On the right is ubuntu/GNOME, showing the same app (vscode).
The 3 elements above the app uses quite a lot of screen real estate. (about 10 lines worth in code editor)

Is there a way to show vscode app using 100% of the screen area?

I thought about custom theming GNOME or maybe switch to other DE's, but I know surprisingly little about modern DE's in Linux today.
Any suggestions and pointers are absolutely appreciated!

(Last time I tried it was a Mandrake Linux 5.3 with kernel 2.2.7! boy hasn't Linux got better in every aspect haha.)

Comment: hi! thanks for the comment. I posted here because I love ubuntu but not so much yet for GNOME. If anyone has a suggestion to use other DEs like xfce, kde, I'd love to find out more as long as it runs on ubuntu.

Comment: This is helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394111/how-to-remove-the-title-bar-of-gnome-applications

Answer (score 2):

First note that the linux desktop is a very diverse ecosystem, with differing views and implementations of UI aspects between desktop environment and graphical toolkits.

What you can do to save vertical screen real estate very much depends on the desktop you use and how it is conceived. An answer to your current question only can be very generic.

- Many apps support full screen mode. This removes all window decorations. In Gnome Desktop, you can set a shortcut key to full screen any application in "Settings", "Keyboard", section "Windows".
- GTK applications with client side decorations do not use a traditional title bar and abolished the traditional menu. So by design, such applications already conform to what you are looking for. You see in most Gnome Shell applications like Files, Editor, etc. Also Mozilla products, Firefox and Thunderbird, allow to hide the menu bar, providing a hamburger menu, or F10 and Alt-hotkeys for access to the menu bar.
- Only when running Gnome Shell on Xorg, extensions such as [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) allow to remove a legacy window titlebar.
- Many desktops support hiding the top bar to gain vertical space.
- On the Plasma desktop and on the Mate desktop, one can replace the application menu per window to a global application menu in the top bar like in MacOS.
- Although tiling window managers are probably not anymore for the big masses, they are aimed to always fill available screen space and do not work with legacy window titlebars.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Linux GUI is very diverse indeed. Perhaps can you provide me a more detailed guidance, if I limit my question to "Use VScode / on any DE that is reasonably easily installable on ubuntu20.04/22.04" ?

Comment: That would still be a very broad question, and the idea here is not to change questions fundamentally after they have been answered. Feel free to settle on a desktop environment, look for options yourself, and ask a specific question on the topic if it arises. In the mean time, please "accept" this answer if it answered your current question.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a global menu like in macOS in Gnome with some tweaking.
I use XFCE4 Panel alongside the Gnome Panel.
You'll need Dash to Panel as well in order to keep Gnome panel features such as notifications.
I added Pop!_OS windows tiling.

I created a script you can use if you want to.

https://github.com/M-Rick/ZorinOS/tree/main/Global%20menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this in Ubuntu by installing the extension manager for gnome: sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager and then searching for "undecorate window" extension and the last option when you press alt+space is undecorate. It's not a perfect solution by any means but it's workable. Hope it helps.

Comment: it's interesting but it conflicts with the side bar auto hide