How to make digikam's title-bar disappear - or merge with "global menu bar"?
I'd like to recoup ~1cm worth of vertical screen real estate when using Ubuntu (24.04.1 LTS) with digiKam (8.4.0):
Any way to make digikam's (useless) title-bar disappear - or merge it with the "global menu bar" (like Firefox does it, for example)?
(A small aside: any way to have digikam always launch in "maximized"-mode?)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394111/how-to-remove-the-title-bar-of-gnome-applications
